# Create Wordpress custom fields but not as meta_data

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on project using Wordpress API and I would like to ask you if there is any way to create custom fields for wordpress posts but not as meta_data fields?

I'm using normal way to create this fields but it save fields as meta_data with their own ID, key and value and this makes my app - api communication tougher to maintain.

For example I have something like this:

`...
"menu_order": 0,
"meta_data": [
   {
     "id": 90391,
     "key": "cds_quantity",
     "value": "9999"
   },
],
"_links":
...`

and I'll be happy to archieve something like this:

`...
"menu_order": 0,
"meta_data": [],
"cds_quantity": 9999,
"_links":
...`

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: An alternative to get the desired output could be [rest_post_dispatch](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_post_dispatch/) to modify the content before sending. There you could filter out the `meta_data` and write it into your `cds_quantitiy` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to work custom fields without meta_data

Wordpress work for any custom fields as meta_data, See here :-

https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

if you need without meta_data you need to save this data from other table, not WordPress table

Answer (score 0):

As Khalid wrote, my goal is not possible to archive the way I wanted but I found another way for those who use REST API.

When you create custom post_meta you can add it to API response with this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_product_object', 'wc_rest_api_add_custom_data_to_product', 90, 2 );
function wc_rest_api_add_custom_data_to_product( $response, $post ) {

  $response->data['your_api_key'] = get_post_meta( $post->id, '_post_meta_key', true );

  return $response;

}
```

Maybe this will be helpful.

Cheers.